# Slide focus to TextField in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been learning flutter for last few days and I encountered a problem while developing my app. So I have a basic form containing all the basic input fields and after a user clicks the submit button the app checks for the validity of the text field. If there is some wrong entry the app moves focus back to the text field.

How can I move focus back to the Text Field?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

```
var focusNode = FocusNode();
var textField = TextField(focusNode: focusNode);

FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
// or 
focusNode.requestFocus();
```

See also

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html
- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Comment: If you want to do the opposite i.e. remove focus from a TextField, the simple way is to call: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); //remove focus`

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki there's now a dedicated `unfocus` method. `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/unfocus.html

Comment: Note that for preventing memory leaks you have to dispose your focusNode in your widget's dispose method. `@override void dispose() { focusNode.dispose(); super.dispose(); }`

Comment: @SamanSattari I don't think this is necessary in general. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you can see this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299240/why-focusnode-needs-to-dispose-in-flutter

Answer (score 56):

```
 TextField(
      autofocus: true,
);
```

Comment: This is not a solution as this autofocuses the textfield but not necessarily what OP asked. Since he wants to refocus another textfield.

Answer (score 15):

Use

**`FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();`**

---

[image]

```
Column(
  children: [
    TextField(...), // 1st TextField
    TextField(...), // 2nd TextField
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus(), // This is what you need
      child: Text("Go back"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

FocusNode name_focus = FocusNode();

```
                     TextField(
                        controller: name_Controller,
                        focusNode: name_focus,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorText: name_validate ? 'Enter Name' : null,
                          labelStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: HexColor(HexColor.gray_text)),
                          labelText: "Name",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: HexColor(HexColor.gray))),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: HexColor(HexColor.gray))),
                        ),
                      ),
```

check validation name is not empty automatic scroll my page for show

```
 if(name_Controller.text.isEmpty){
   name_validate=true;
   name_focus.requestFocus();
  }
```