# Cursor and text not showing in TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the TextField, my cursor and the text I type in the text field are not displayed. It seems that I do everything as always, but for some reason nothing is displayed. Please tell me what could be my mistake?

**body**

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                child: MySearchWidget(
                  onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

**MySearchWidget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
          onPressed: () {
            _onBackPressed(context);
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            constants.Assets.arrowLeft,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 14,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
              color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              onChanged: onChanged,
              style: constants.Styles.textFieldTextStyleWhite,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15,
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                prefixIcon: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    constants.Assets.search,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is it nested in a Form Widget?

Comment: no, I didn't wrap it in a Form widget

Comment: It's like it's not necessary?

Comment: I guess that might be a problem, TextFormFields are supposed to be inside a Form at some point, I think that you could do a try

Comment: Didn't work, still got the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Align widget wrapping your prefixIcon.

```dart
TextFormField(
    onChanged: onChanged,
    style: constants.Styles.textFieldTextStyleWhite,
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
        ),
    border: InputBorder.none,
    prefixIcon: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/svg/logo.svg',
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution helped me)
Please tell me more, but how can I now align the image and make it smaller? Because by removing Align, my image has greatly increased

Comment: Didn't saw that you already had set a size, so you can try to use a FittedBox to force it to scale down.

Comment: I wrapped the icon in a container and set the padding and everything was as it should be.

Comment: And could they help with one more question, do I need that when the page opens, focus is immediately placed on the TextField and the keyboard opens without clicking on the field? Is it possible to release it? The autofocus: true method doesn't help.

Comment: I think that this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592201/19178917 if I understood correctly.

Comment: I need Focus a text field as soon as it’s visible (when open page)