# Focus next TextField after Autofill in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm currently trying to replicate the autofill behaviour that can be seen when filling forms in Safari on iOS: When a text field is filled using autofill, it automatically focuses the next field.

In Flutter for iOS, I use `AutofillGroup` together with `AutofillHints` and `TextInputAction.next` on the individual TextFields. This results in correct autofill but after the field has been filled,  it just remains focused.

I already tried adding a listener to `onEditingComplete` and then manually change focus but this doesn't get fired when autofill was used. Also I wasn't able to find any other callback neither on Text(Form)Field nor on AutofillGroup that could help.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592099/slide-focus-to-textfield-in-flutter) may help you. Maybe once you call your Autofill methods you can request a focus on fields that are empty.

Comment: Hey @FrankRayYager, thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is not about setting focus to a field but about how to get notified that autofill happened as there currently seems to be no callbacks  for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I was checking this and I didn't find an API available so I created a custom/hacky solution:

```dart
class MyTextFieldWithAutofillEvent extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextFieldWithAutofillEvent({
    this.controller,
    this.inputDecoration,
    this.autofillHints,
    this.textInputAction,
    super.key,
  });

  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final InputDecoration? inputDecoration;
  final List<String>? autofillHints;
  final TextInputAction? textInputAction;

  @override
  State<MyTextFieldWithAutofillEvent> createState() =>
      _MyTextFieldWithAutofillEventState();
}

class _MyTextFieldWithAutofillEventState
    extends State<MyTextFieldWithAutofillEvent> {
  String currentValue = '';
  final debouncer = Debouncer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: widget.inputDecoration,
      autofillHints: widget.autofillHints,
      textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        if ((currentValue.length - newValue.length).abs() >= 2 ||
            (currentValue != newValue &&
                newValue.length == currentValue.length)) {
          debouncer.run(
            () {
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            },
          );
        }
        currentValue = newValue;
      },
      onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus,
      onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
    );
  }
}

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({this.milliseconds = 1000});

  void run(VoidCallback action) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

Basically I created a wrapper for your TextField and it triggers the focus under 2 conditions:

- When the length of the new text/value is more than 2 (normally this is true when we use the autofill).
- When the length are equal but the values are different.

any of those conditions will activate the trigger and I used a "debouncer" to wait "1 second" (you can change it) to move to the next focus.